# Magento add image to media gallery causing duplicate images with _1 appended

Tags: product-images, media

So I have a folder of images and a php array that has sku's for keys and an array of images i need to add to that sku's gallery as its value ...for example:

```
['A2052'] => ['tmp/A2052-1.jpg', 'tmp/A2052-2.jpg']
```

I run through this array and try to add the images to the products with this code:

```
    foreach ($skuImageMap as $sku => $images) {
        $ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
        if ($ourProduct) {
            foreach ($images as $index => $imagePath) {
                if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
                    try {
                        $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, null, false, false);
                        $ourProduct->save();
                        echo "The image $imagePath was added to $sku successfully : $imageCount \n";
                        $imageCount++;
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo "There was an issue saving image $imagePath to $sku :" . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "The image $imagePath does not exist.\n";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "The product $sku does not exist \n";
        }
    }
```

The issue is that when I run this script I get two images saved to the gallery for each image. One correct one and another with _1 appended (which obviously doesnt exist so its broken). I can't seem to stop this duplication. Why is it adding two images on every save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely its because you are saving the product after every `addImagetoMediaGallery` moving it out of the loop of both images should suffice.

Untested but like this perhaps?

```
foreach ($skuImageMap as $sku => $images) {
    $ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    $saveFlag = true;
    if ($ourProduct) {
        foreach ($images as $index => $imagePath) {
            if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
                try {
                    $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, null, false, false);
                    $imageCount++;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $saveFlag = false;
                    echo "There was an issue saving image $imagePath to $sku :" . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
                }
            } else {
                $saveFlag = false;
                echo "The image $imagePath does not exist.\n";
            }
        }

        if($saveFlag) {
            try {
                $ourProduct->save();
                echo "The image $imagePath was added to $sku successfully : $imageCount \n";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                zend_debug::dump($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    } else {
        echo "The product $sku does not exist \n";
    }
}
```