# Duplicated images when adding image to gallery programmatically in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, gallery

I'm trying add image to product gallery by downloading image file from internet to my magento server and add this as main image in gallery by `addImageToMediaGallery` method:

```
                $imageToAdd = 'http://example.com/some_image.jpg';
                $uploadedImgsDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/uploaded-imgs';
                $imageFilePathForUpload = $uploadedImgsDir . '/' . (new SplFileInfo($imageToAdd))->getFilename();
                file_put_contents($imageFilePathForUpload, fopen($imageToAdd, 'r'));
                // Add Image to Gallery
                $imgCfg = ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'];
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageFilePathForUpload, $imgCfg, false, false);
```

However, In product gallery in I see my image (with url = http://example-magento.com/image1.jpg) with 'image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail' = **false** and other image (with **404** url - with **_1** adition in url - = http://example-magento.com/image1_1.jpg):

[image]

Please help (any idea would be appreciated). Or Please request more information I'll add them in my question.

Comment: Very similar to: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69944/magento-add-image-to-media-gallery-causing-duplicate-images-with-1-appended

Comment: duplicate (??) of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84472/addimagetomediagallery-creates-two-image-entries-while-having-only-one-file

Comment: I fixed my problem. In free time maybe I'll add info how I fixed.  Write here if you my solution faster.